# is there any python lib to query gcs bucket location

Tags: google-cloud-storage

We are developing for EU region, and one requirement is before writing to a gcs bucket, we need to make sure the bucket is in EU region, our creds has only `Cloud Storage Object Admin` permission, so we can not use the cloud.storage.Client(...).get_bucket() call
is there any other api entrypoint without the get_bucket permission to programmatically retrieve bucket location information?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find tools, software libraries or other off-site resources are off-topic according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Comment: You should control your environment and to know where your resources are deployed. Checking resource deployment at runtime is not a good practice (not efficient at least)